# How to do the password managers auto fill username, password in form?

Tags: javascript, html, backend

I want to make a password manager (Vault) which stores username, password and website. When the user of my Vault click on particular site through my web-application I want to redirect and auto-fill this username and password. On the clicked site.

I am have made databases and stuff. But how do I auto-populate the form. If I don't know the id or name of text box?

If there are some api's or ML algos which can parse and tell me id's for text and password. I thank you in adv. Also if someone knows how google knows which field to fill with what, I am available to hear that as well.

Comment: You'll have to create a browser extension, you cannot populate the fields from another website

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply @blex . I know that. But still how do I know where to fill what...   EDIT: using python script I tried to parse ICICI bank site, They had make about 20 tesxt boxes and named them as dummy1,dummy2... and one of them was vaild. So how do I know which one is real one(which I need).

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/bitwarden/browser/blob/38e4ba087930e491628435201b4796fb4bfe8463/src/services/autofill.service.ts#L188

Finally found this. They basically hard code and search for them in html page. Well this was interesting don't you think.